# Join multiple tables and group by

Tags: sql-server

I am creating query using 4 table join I want to make grouping using airbill i tried this one but its not giving exact output

```
SELECT Item.Name, TLSaleOrder.Description As SoldAs, Containers.NetWeight, UnitsOfMeasure.UOM, Containers.ContainerNumber, Containers.SealNumber,SupplierInvoice.airbill
FROM Containers 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Item ON Containers.ItemID = Item.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN UnitsOfMeasure ON UnitsOfMeasure.ID = Containers.UOM 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TransactionHeader SupplierInvoice ON SupplierInvoice.ID=Containers.SupplierInvoiceID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TransactionLine TLSupplierInvoice ON TLSupplierInvoice.TransactionID = SupplierInvoice.ID AND TLSupplierInvoice.LineType='Detail' AND TLSupplierInvoice.LineSubType='Product' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TransactionHeader SaleOrder ON SaleOrder.ID = TLSupplierInvoice.SOTransID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TransactionLine TLSaleOrder ON TLSaleOrder.TransactionID = SaleOrder.ID AND TLSaleOrder.LineType='Detail' AND TLSaleOrder.LineSubType='Product' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TransactionHeader Invoice ON Invoice.ParentTransactionID = SaleOrder.ID 
WHERE Invoice.ID= 13 
group by SupplierInvoice.airbill
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'make grouping using airbill' ?  Do you mean group by that column and then use aggregates of the other columns?  what is your desired result?

Comment: By "Not giving exact output" you mean that you get an error? This statement can't work in SQL Server

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.